# all test return json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:

Tags: python, json, flask

I use Flask, and all my endpoints is correct and return the correct results

```
@APP.route('/movies', methods=['GET'])
def get_movies():
    movies = Movie.query.all()
    current_movies = paginate_movies(request, movies)

    # if there are no movies abort 404
    if len(current_movies) == 0:
        abort(404)

    # return data to view
    return jsonify({
        'success': True,
        'movies': current_movies,
        'total_movies': len(movies)
    })
```

test_app.py

```
    def test_get_movies(self):
        res= self.client().get('/movies')
        data = json.loads(res.data)

        self.assertEqual(data['success'], True)
        self.assertTrue(data['movies'])
        self.assertTrue(data['total_movies'])
```

the result of test
this result is for all the test

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_movies (__main__.CastingAgencyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_app.py", line 40, in test_get_movies
    data = json.loads(res.data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.298s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

the value of res is :
<Response streamed [404 NOT FOUND]>

Comment: Please don't use images to show any error messages you're receiving. Instead, please [edit] your question to include your error message as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: what is the value of ```res.data```?

Comment: the value of res is : <Response streamed [404 NOT FOUND]>